# Query Limit for Google Contacts API

Tags: php, google-api, synchronization, google-contacts-api

I am currently trying to make a syncing operation between my Database and Gmail's contacts. 
My first initial sync, downloading/uploading over 1,000 contacts per user might throw some errors up in gmails face.

Is there any work-arounds? What is the limitations to having many contacts?

My understanding is that it is limited per IP, and not per User... is this correct?

I hope that someone can share some info on this, I have searched the web, but haven't found the best of resources... Thoughts?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually received a response from Google.

> The query is currently per user and is quite high though there is a
>   limit in the number of queries per second, per hour and per half a day
>   you can send. Unfortunately, we don't publicly communicate on these
>   values but I can assure you that normal applications (not spamming
>   Google's servers) shouldn't have any issues.
>
> Also, when syncing, please make sure to use the updated-min query
>   parameter to only request contacts that have been updated since the
>   provided time and use batch-request when sending requests to the API
>   as it will perform multiple operations while consuming only one
>   request on the user's quota.

Hopefully this helps someone else if in need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a limitation on accessing the Google API (at least on Google Maps API) on an IP basis. The only workaround I was abble to find is to use proxy servers (or tor).